# In Python how can I print the rows in my text file in a random order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file formatted in three columns:

```
1   10045   0.120559958
1   157465  0.590642951
2   222471  0.947959795
2   222473  0.083341617
3   222541  0.054014337
3   222588  0.060296547
4   237571  0.646742879
```

Here is my code that prints my file in the three column format shown above:

```
import csv
import random
import os.path

def filename ():

filename = 'filename.txt'
with open ("filename.txt", "r") as data_file:
for line in data_file.readlines():
    line = line.strip().split()
    print (line [0], line [1], line[2])
```

How can I alter my code so that it prints the rows of the three columns in a random order? My desired output is for example:

```
2   222473  0.083341617
4   237571  0.646742879
3   222588  0.060296547
1   10045   0.120559958
1   157465  0.590642951
2   222471  0.947959795
3   222541  0.054014337
```

UPDATE:
I have successfully printed my file randomly. However, how can I go about removing the extra blank spaces between each line?

```
 2  202174949   0.029547574

 5  211764876   0.605756554

 3  188664399   0.209919535

 2  219396633   0.271415602

 8  152970529   0.371399522

 2  86250214    0.765947161

 2  51751412    0.382815804

 6  93732369    0.230918546
```

I have tried using:

```
 splitted_line = line.strip("\n").split(";")
```

But there is no change in my output. The extra spaces are still there.

Comment: Read all the lines into a list then use ```random.shuffle``` to rearrange the list then print the lines from the list.

Comment: please, use `for line in data_file:` instead of `for line in data_file.readlines():`

Comment: unrelated: you could use `print(*line.split())` instead of `line = line.strip().split(); print (line [0], line [1], line[2])` (assuming you want to print all columns). Note: you don't need `.strip()` before `.split()`; try: `' a b '.split()`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will consider them @J.F.Sebastian

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you give me any additional suggestions? @J.F.Sebastian

Comment: Try to limit your question to one issue. If you have found another error; create a separate question. You can always link to the previous question for context if necessary (but try to make each question self-sufficient). Neither the code in my comment nor the code in @mgilson's answer would double newlines unless the input already contains them or you've changed the provided code (include a [minimal but complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your new question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just read the file's lines into a list and call [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) on it.  Then print the lines.

```
import random
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as fin:
    lines = list(fin)

random.shuffle(lines)
for line in lines:
    print line,  # the trailing comma suppresses the newline since the line already has that.
```

for python2 -> python3 compatibility, you can use the `print` function

```
from __future__ import print_function

# ...

for line in lines:
    print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir it was so simple. My brain being so fried from my project I guess all I needed to do was take a step back and think. Thanks again @mgilson

Comment: @SamWilliams: the code may merge lines if the last line has no newline at the end. To avoid it, you could use `lines = file.read().splitlines()` to strip newlines and `print(line)` to insert them later.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- good point.  `print(line.rstrip('\n'))` would also work :-)

Comment: @mgilson: yes. I prefer to offload internal loops into C code (`.splitlines()` removes newlines from all lines at once).

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you give me any additional suggestions? @mgilson

Comment: @SamWilliams -- I'm not sure exactly what you're going for there.  Why are you splitting on `;` and how are you printing it?